# How to switch off assembly version checking for a .net Application

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I'm a developer of a C#/.net program that can run as a standalone application but also as a plug in a 3rd party application.

I have problems with assembly loading because of versions checks when running the program as a plug in.

Some of the NuGet package I use depend on for example Newtonsoft Json but in different versions. Let’s say NuGet package A needs Newtonsoft Json >= 12 and NuGet package B needs Newtonsoft Json >= 13.
This is no problem when I run the program stand alone as the NuGet packages state the dependency is >= and Visual Studio seems to autogenerate some redirect information and puts it in the dll.config or exe.config files.
This information looks like this:

```
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-13.0.0.0" newVersion="13.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

But apparently when my program is loaded as a plug in by the 3rd Party Application this redirect info gets ignored and the >= dependencies turn, by some black magic, into == dependencies.
So when I use the Newtonsoft json lib in version 12 my code using stuff from NuGet package B crashes with a assembly load exceptions because of the wrong version
and if I use the Newtonsoft json lib in version 13 (which is of course what I want to use as it is the newer version) my code using stuff from NuGet package A crashes with a assembly load exceptions because of the wrong version.

So just by having my program be loaded as a plugin I got into some kind of dll hell.

I now know of 2 bad ways to fix this:

1. I can down grade NuGet package B to an older version that also depends on Newtonsoft Json >= 12
2. I can edit the 3rdParty.exe.config file to add

```
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-13.0.0.0" newVersion="13.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

And everything runs nicely

Now 1) is bad because any update of a NuGet package might lead to a assembly load exception which is only detected at run time when the actually feature is used
and 2) is bad because I have to edit a file I don't control, so every time I update the 3rdParty program I have to edit it again

**Are there any better solutions to this problem?**

**Can I somehow in Visual Studio or Windows or .NET or wherever switch off the version check during assembly loading so that >= dependencies don't turn into == dependencies?**

My program has many dependencies and Newtonsoft json was only one example. The project is haunted by this dll hell since years now and no developer dares to touch the NuGet packages versions  which has obvious downsides.
But when a developer does add/update packages we do run into the described problems

My program is written in C# and targeting 64 bit & .net Framework 4.7.2. and running on Windows 10. I think the 3rd Party Program is using .net Framework 4.5.2.

Thanks in Advance for any help

Comment: I favor option 2.  It gives you the most flexibility.

Comment: Erm my question was if there is a third possibility so solve this mess ... I now made this question bold ;-)

Comment: The likelihood of anyone else editing that file is quite small.

Comment: This is true, but I still would need to check after every release of the 3rdParty program if it changed and if yes merge it with my changes. Also if I add or update a nuget package to my program I would have to check if this generates new assembly redirects in myApp.dll.config and copy them to 3rdParty.exe.config if necessary...

Answer (score 0):

Imho option 2 is not a *bad way* - it is the way how .NET is supposed to work: when adding a dependency, you have to handle transitive dependency redirects as well. That's exactly the reason why you see all the binding redirects within `app.config`/`web.config`, even when referencing assemblies originating from .NET itself (e. g. `System.Net.Http`). If you don't like this, don't use .NET

I'd highly discourage disabling the version check. The chance that you will encounter some nasty, hard to debug behaviors is quite high.

Comment: The autogenerated assembly redirects for my program are present in the app.dll.config files and positioned next to the dlls themselves which the 3rdParty.exe loads as a plugin... my problem is they don't seem to count anymore when my dlls are loaded by the 3rd party program .. only the redirects in the 3rdParty.exe.config and I would call me manually editing this 3rdParty.exe.config to make everything work ... bad.
Or am I simply mistaken and the .config files of my dlls should count?